# Issue in creating dataset for traing model in vertex AI:

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataset, sentiment-analysis, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

I'm creating a dataset in vertex AI to train model but getting this issue after uploading CSV file. I've chosen tabular as data type and my file contains two columns(news description and its sentiment)

I tried different csv files but getting same issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzykV.png)